# Prove the irreducibility of $P(x)$ which satisfies: $xP(x-1)=(x-2022)P(x)+2022$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove the irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of $P(x)$ which satisfies: $xP(x-1)=(x-2022)P(x)+2022, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempts**
I thought of substituting $x$ for $0$ and $x$ for $2022$, but that yielded no results. I have also attempted the Eisenstein criterion but that does not work as well.

Comment: Hint : You can show $P(x)=1$.

Comment: How come? What did you do, what tool did you use to get that? Can you elaborate/

Comment: Unfortunately , I can only give a complete solution if the question is considered to have enough context. But you can try it yourself : With setting $x=2022$ , you were already on the right track. Continue with induction.

Comment: @Peter No, I think $P(x) = 1 + \prod_{k=0}^{2021}(x-k)$ is another solution.

Comment: @aschepler I think you got a point. So Peter, basically I'm subtracting $x$ from both side and set $Q(x)=P(x)-1$ then , $xQ(x-1)=(x-2022)Q(x)$, right?

Comment: Do you see how I came up with that solution? Did you determine the values $P(0)$ and $P(2021)$? How about $P(1)$ or $P(2020)$?

Comment: @aschepler Yes sir, actually I think the solution is very cool. I solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got $xP(x-1)=(x-2022)P(x)+2022$ equals $x(P(x-1)-1)=(x-2022)[P(x)-1]$,

I substitute $P(x)-1=Q(x)$ then I got $xQ(x-1)=(x-2022)Q(x)$

Substitute $x=2022$  we have $Q(2021)=0$ thus $x=2021$ is a root of $Q(x)$

This implies $x(x-2022)Q_1(x-1)=(x-2022)(x-2021)Q_1(x)$

Thus $xQ_1(x-1)=(x-2021)Q_1(x)$

Do the same thing for $Q_1, Q_2,...,Q_{2021}$ you will have
\begin{align}
P(x)= 1+\prod_{i=0}^{2021}(x-i)
\end{align}

Using Eisenstein criterion for $p=2$ yields the result!